# Understanding Async/Await

Tags: c#

I know how to use tasks and such to get it to work without async/await, but all the examples and video's ive watched i still can't figure it out. Some people have it done by Creating a task in the button click and then awaiting that task?

So far:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var vari = await GetId();
    comboBox1.Items.Add(vari);
}
private  Task<string> GetId() {
    return  Task.Run(() => {
         return getstring();
    });
}
public string getstring() {
    Thread.Sleep(5000);//simulate long task
    string d = "Example";
    return d;
}
```

I've tried it a couple different ways, Is this the correct way of doing it? is there a way I can eliminate the running of another task in the `GetId()` method, and just return a string there?

Comment: What type of work is it?  Is it CPU bound work, IO, or what?

Comment: Please read this great resource about `async` and `await` here: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-0-introduction.html

Comment: That looks good.  You aren't running "another task" in `GetId`.  You are creating a task that can run your `getstring` logic in the background so your UI is responsive.

Comment: @Brandon so returning a task.run like that is the normal way of executing a method async and returning a value?

Comment: It is very unclear where "just sample" code starts - indeed `button1_Click` is correct way for async event handling (as covered in many SO question and other articles), but the other 2 methods are completely against good `async`/`await` practices (but they may be part of "sample only" code and not related to the question...). Consider clarifying.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Lets pretend the getstring method actually does something useful,What would be wrong with it and how would you change the GetId() method to be correct async practice?

Comment: @Dylan there are many ways to get a `Task`.  `Task.Run` is useful when you have a slow synchronous method that you must use but do not want to block your current thread.  You use `Task.Run` to run the slow method on the thread pool.  In your "sample" case, you could use `Task.Delay()` instead of `Thread.Sleep()` and you'd make `getstring` a truly synchronous method that returned a `Task` that you could await.  `getstring` would look like: `Task<string> getString(){ await Task.Delay(3000); return "Example"; }`.  In this case you wouldn't need or use `Task.Run`

Comment: @Brandon so if I had some sort of Sql execution going on from the getstring() method, it would still lock up the UI? Shouldn't the fact that I ran that method from a different thread(task) still make the UI usuable?

Comment: @Dylan correct.  Ideally you'd use an asynchronous Sql API that returned Tasks or Observables.  But if you are using the sync API, it would indeed block your thread.  Running such code within `Task.Run` is exactly how you push it onto a different thread and keep your UI usable.  .e.g pretend you had `db.Execute...(...)` in place of `Thread.Sleep()` and your code would be a good way to do it.

Comment: Thank you! You helped me grasp this a bit better :)

Comment: @Dylan `getstring` is not really asynchronous method right now - so you have to do all kinds of hacks to get it working on non-UI thread. If it is IO bound - make it proper `async` and call `XxxxxAsync` variants of whatever methods you are using. For CPU bound - whatever you have is ok as you need guarantee to get off UI thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is there a way I can eliminate the running of another task in the GetId() method, and just return a string there?

`Task.Run` just executes the operation on a new thread. If you don't do it and call `GetId` directly, it will just run on the UI thread, blocking the UI for 5 seconds.

Just marking a method `async` doesn't make it run on a new thread, it only means that the method uses `await`. If you did this:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var vari = await GetId();
    comboBox1.Items.Add(vari);
}
private async Task<string> GetId() {
    Thread.Sleep(5000);//simulate long task
    string d = "Example";
    return d;
}
```

it would compile (with a warning because `GetId` doesn't use `await`), but it would execute synchronously on the UI thread.

What you could do, however, is replace `Thread.Sleep` (which is synchronous) with `Task.Delay` (which is asynchronous):

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var vari = await GetId();
    comboBox1.Items.Add(vari);
}
private async Task<string> GetId() {
    await Task.Delay(5000); //simulate long task
    string d = "Example";
    return d;
}
```

In this case, there is no new thread involved. In the background, `Task.Delay` just sets a kind of timer that will execute the rest of the method (following the `await`) when the delay is elapsed. The UI thread will be free to do something else in the meanwhile.

Comment: This is also good explanation of difference between mocking CPU intensive task (Sleep) vs. long IO bound tasks (Delay).

Comment: Thanks Thomas for the explanation!